# How to change the value of column/Field for the repeated ID

Tags: sql

I have Dataset/Table of 50k something like follwoing:

```
ID  value
100 A1
100 DC
100 DC
100 DC
105 DC
105 C9
105 DC
105 DC
110 A3
110 DC
110 DC
115 DC
115 A4
115 DC
120 C2
120 DC
120 DC
```

I would like to make two types of change value colmn.

1. IF any id have values like A1, A2, A3... then I want to keep this record but want to change other values to D1 for same ID.
2. IF any id have values not like  A1, A2, A3...(for example C2, C9..) then I want to keep this record but also want to change other values to C9( because that one of it ID has C9 and same logic.

I want make change my dateset/Table and finally looks like following.

```
ID  value
100 A1
100 D1
100 D1
100 D1
105 C9
105 C9
105 C9
105 C9
110 A3
110 D1
110 D1
115 D1
115 A4
115 D1
120 C2
120 C2
120 C2
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database and analytics tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using (you say you have a "table" so I assume you *are* using a SQL database).

Comment: Why all records for 120 have `C2` value? *For example* is treated as some sample data, not the rule, so `DC` is also *not equal to A1, A2, A3...*. Please clarify the logic of calculation and what to do if none of `An` and `Cn` is present

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery we can get a new value as

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, value,
    /* If first character is other than A then new value will be D1 */
    CASE
      WHEN LEFT(value,1) != 'A'
         THEN 'D1'
         ELSE value
    END as new_value
    FROM tbl
    /* Get all rows whose ID is same as A's */
    WHERE id IN (
           /* Get IDs of rows where value starts with A */
            SELECT id
            FROM tbl
            WHERE value LIKE 'A%'
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, value,
    /* If first value is not C, then query to get value for C as new value */
    CASE
      WHEN LEFT(value,1) != 'C'
        THEN (SELECT value FROM tbl WHERE id = z.id AND value LIKE 'C%')
        ELSE value
    END AS new_value
    FROM tbl AS z
    /* Get all rows whose ID is same as C's */
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM tbl
        /* Get all rows starting with C and excluding A's */
        WHERE id NOT IN (
            /* Get IDs of rows where value starts with A */
            SELECT id
            FROM tbl
            WHERE value LIKE 'A%'
        )
        AND value LIKE 'C%'
    )
) AS o
ORDER BY o.id ASC;
```

The query has 2 major parts which are merged using `UNION ALL`. The first part addresses problem 1, and the second problem 2. You can also run 2 queries separately to solve the problem.

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c5761/26)

Comment: Thank you @ Samir, I still not got what I want.

Comment: I wanted to keep Ai for which it appeared and IF any id have values not like A1, A2, A3...(for example C2, C9 in my example but I do have P1, P2.., G1,G2,....) then I want to keep this record at the same time also want to change other values to respective one for the same id. @Samir